# Angular Material Date Picker cannot be dynamically named

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am generating a form dynamically and I need to name my controls according to the model.

I am working with Angular 5 and Angular-Material 5.

However, I am unable to name the date picker (Mat-DatePicker) dynamically as I get the following error.

> InstrumentSearchComponent.html:27 ERROR TypeError:
>   this._datepicker._registerInput is not a function

This is how I tried to create my control with dynamic name which resulted in the above error.

```
 <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dynamicName" placeholder="{{ dynamicLabel }}">
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dynamicName"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #{{dynamicName}}></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Both **dynamicName** and **dynamicLabel** defined in the associated TS file and coming from the model I defined for the fields.

If I remove the dynamic names and replace them all with static names such as datePicker1 or picker1 then it all works but I am then struggling to combine the statically named control and bind it to my model.

example of statically named control which works.

```
 <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{ dynamicLabel }}">
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Any suggestions guys? Thanks

Comment: Why not use `id` (`id="{{dynamicName}}"`) rather than a template variable (#picker)? You can get a reference to a component with an id easily enough.

Comment: Thanks Richard; I endup using formControlName on the associated input field. I only have a single date time field on my search form so I can live with that. But when I will have 2 or more date controls then I will have to find a way of naming two date pickers differently to each other :) Thanks buddy

Answer (score 13):

When one assigns `#identifier` to a particular element in the angular template, one is simply creating a local variable with that name. Hence it wont matter even if you use the same name as the scope of it is just limited for that loop cycle.

Assuming you are creating a form dynamically based on some data in an array `formData`

```
formData = [
    {
       id=0,
       type="date-picker",
       label= "label 1"
    }, 
    ...
]
```

Below code should do your job in this case.

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let field of formData">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{ field.Label }}">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

As each loop runs `#picker` is reinitialised with new input element which inturn is passed to `[matDatepicker]`

This is same as reinitialising a variable in a for loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < formData.length ; i++ ){

    // assume <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker> similar to below line of code.

    let picker = document.createElement("INPUT");
}
```

Comment: can you explain how does this actually work `<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>`? it looks like creating *the same* reference of `#picker` a number of times in a loop. same for `[for]="picker"` and `[matDatepicker]="picker"`. why can't this be done like e.g. `[matDatepicker]="{{ i + 'picker' }}"` to distinguish one picker from another?

Comment: `[matDatepicker]` expects a variable and not a unique string value. If you have a look at the for loop given in as example, `#picker` is nothing but `let picker` where it is assigned with an object referencing to that datepicker. In each iteration the variable `#picker` is reinitialised with a new datepicker object in that scope.

Comment: the 'scope' is the keyword in my case, I'd seen them as *the same* variables 'side by side' until now while they actually differs in scopes. ty for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Remove interpolation from the datepicker and use the dynamic template reference name directly.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dynamicName" placeholder="{{ dynamicLabel }}" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dynamicName"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dynamicName></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

If dynamic date picker is not what you have and you have created a local variable for the input box as well, make sure that the name of the variable is not the same as the local variable you created for the date picker. see below:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" name="someDate" [ngModel]="someVariable.DATE" #dateRef="ngModel">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Notice the local variable for input field is named **dateRef** and local variable for date-picker is named **datePicker** and they are not same.

Answer (score 0):

I was a similar problem after enabling ivy compiler in a project with angular 9 with material. And I have no idea why this works with ivy compiler disabled.

And in my case, the problem is with the variable name duplicated in the template.

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-4">
      <mat-label>Birth Date: </mat-label>
      <input
        formControlName="birthDate"
        matInput
        [matDatepicker]="birthdt"
        (click)="birthdt.open()"
        (focus)="birthdt.open()"
        #birthdt   <==== HERE, after removed, works 
      />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle
        matSuffix
        [for]="birthdt"
      ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker
        startView="multi-year"
        [startAt]="startDate"
        touchUi
        #birthdt  <==== AND HERE
      ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

So, that's it .